# Problems when positioning buttons with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having trouble creating buttons in tkinter, I've tried doing it in different ways, but I haven't reached the solution.

It turns out that one of the requirements that they have made me when making this calculator is to create three text boxes and eleven buttons, so when I create the positioning of the boxes and I want to place the buttons they do nothing, if I try to tell them to position in column 3, row 4 is not positioned.

[Image of the code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eHDh.png)

This is the code, if you see something wrong that I have not been able to see and that is the cause of such an error, I would appreciate it

```py
from tkinter import *
#instancia de calculadora
calculadora = Tk()
#Nombre de la ventana grafica
calculadora.title("Practica calculadora con tkinter")
#tamano de la ventana
calculadora.geometry("600x750")
#color personalizado de la ventana
calculadora.configure(bg="black")

firtDisplay = Entry(calculadora, state="readonly", width=25).place(x=0, y=5)

secondDisplay = Entry(calculadora, state="readonly", width=25).place(x=300, y=5)

thirdDisplay = Entry(calculadora, state="readonly", width=25).place(x=149, y=40)

#Botones
Button(calculadora, text="7", width=15).grid(row=5, column=3)
Button(calculadora, text="8", width=15)
Button(calculadora, text="9", width=15)
 
calculadora.mainloop()
```

Please help would be very good, thank you ...

Comment: You need to specify the number of rows and columns to the grid manager, I think

Comment: Some of your code is commented out. If it's not relevant for the question than please just delete it rather than comment it out.

Comment: If you enter the photo that I leave posted you can see the code without commenting, that part of the commented code is because I have been testing to see if it is something of that that is giving me the error therefore if it is relevant for the program, that this commented does not mean that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must first of all use only one type of geometry management, and then keep it simplest, I've made some changes to show how to use grid manager with some loop.

```
 from tkinter import *
#instancia de calculadora
calculadora = Tk()
#Nombre de la ventana grafica
calculadora.title("Practica calculadora con tkinter")
#tamano de la ventana
#calculadora.geometry("600x750")
#color personalizado de la ventana
#calculadora.configure(bg="black")


r = 0
c = 0
for i in range(0,4):
    if i < 3:
        Entry(calculadora, state="readonly", width=15).grid(row=r, column=c)
    else:
        Checkbutton(calculadora,  width=15, text="/").grid(row=r, column=c)
    c +=1

array = (("7","8","9","x"),("4","5","6","-"),("1","2","3","+"))
r = 1
c = 0
for items in array:
    for i in items:
        index = items.index(i)
        if index < 3:
            Button(calculadora, text=i, width=15).grid(row=r, column=c)
        else:
            Checkbutton(calculadora,  width=15, text=i).grid(row=r, column=c)
        c +=1
    r +=1
    c = 0

calculadora.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing brother, I am new to python and want to improve my logic a bit and then move on to new projects. I'll take what you did as a reference and make some modifications to the interface.

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

You souldn't mix .pack(), .grid(), and .place() in the same master window.